# Form validation in Bootstrap v4.0 not working, required tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```js
/*
Jquery Ajax walk through
1. on click of submit button
2. take ids of inputs and save value to variables
3. put variables in object for easy access
4. make an ajax post request 
*/




$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const name = $("#name").val();
    const email = $("#email").val();
    const message = $("#message").val();
    
    

    const data = {
        name: name, 
        email: email,
        message: message
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/contact", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        contentType: "application/json", // Need this to send proper data to server
        data: JSON.stringify(data), //Form variables
        success: function(sucess) {
            alert("Email has sent");
           
        }
    });
    /* redirects user to link after the form submits */ 
    window.location.assign('/contact:success');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Services Icon link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- AOS Link-->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS Link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/contact.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome Link-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/595056b4d4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Google Font Link-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Adamina&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Logo Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="../images/logo-site.png">


</head>

<body class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container company-col">
        <h5 class="company-logo">August Shah</h5>
        <h5 class="company-contact"><a href="tel:443-681-9485">443-681-9485</a> || <a href="mailto:augustshah@02pilot.com">augustshah@02pilot.com</a> </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    </h1>
    <div class="row position-fixed dropdown">
      <i class=" container fas fa-bars btn  btn-lg" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      </i>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-id" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" data-aos="fade-down"
        id="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio">Web Development</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="/time"> Aviation</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item signin" href="/signin">Signin/Signup</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>



  <section id="contact-section">
    <div class="row contact-row" id="contact-row-id">
      <div class="container contact-container" id="contact-container-id">
        <div class="form" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="2000">
          <h1 class="contact-content">Contact Us</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="/contact"  id="contact">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name </label>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email"> Email </label>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message"> Messages </label>
              <br>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
          </form>
        </div>

        <video autoplay loop muted id="video">
          <source src="../images/contact-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="row questions-row" id="questions-row-id">
    <div class="container align-self-center questions-container" id="questions-container-id">
      <h4 class="questions-content">You may contact us if you have questions or clarifications about our services.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="row ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-content" id="footer-content">
        <h5 class="text-center footer-content">Copyright © 2020 02Pilot LLC</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- jQUERY -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AOS-->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- AOS-->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1500
    });
  </script>
  <!-- AJAX POST LINK-->
  <script src="javascripts/ajax.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello All!
I am trying to add form validation into my site for my contact page. I have run into a snag. No matter what I try none of the bootstrap ways of form validation work. I have tried just the plain required tag, and all of the ways bootstrap explains. I did take out my prevent default in my js file and that didnt change anything. I am at a bit of a loss, any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `required` attibute to your inputs and submit your form `#contact` in Jquery (not button click). Try this one:

```js
/*
Jquery Ajax walk through
1. on click of submit button
2. take ids of inputs and save value to variables
3. put variables in object for easy access
4. make an ajax post request 
*/




$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const name = $("#name").val();
    const email = $("#email").val();
    const message = $("#message").val();
    
    

    const data = {
        name: name, 
        email: email,
        message: message
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/contact", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        contentType: "application/json", // Need this to send proper data to server
        data: JSON.stringify(data), //Form variables
        success: function(sucess) {
            alert("Email has sent");
           
        }
    });
    /* redirects user to link after the form submits */ 
    window.location.assign('/contact:success');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Services Icon link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- AOS Link-->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS Link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/contact.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome Link-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/595056b4d4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Google Font Link-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Adamina&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Logo Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="../images/logo-site.png">


</head>

<body class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container company-col">
        <h5 class="company-logo">August Shah</h5>
        <h5 class="company-contact"><a href="tel:443-681-9485">443-681-9485</a> || <a href="mailto:augustshah@02pilot.com">augustshah@02pilot.com</a> </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    </h1>
    <div class="row position-fixed dropdown">
      <i class=" container fas fa-bars btn  btn-lg" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      </i>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-id" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" data-aos="fade-down"
        id="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio">Web Development</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="/time"> Aviation</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item signin" href="/signin">Signin/Signup</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>



  <section id="contact-section">
    <div class="row contact-row" id="contact-row-id">
      <div class="container contact-container" id="contact-container-id">
        <div class="form" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="2000">
          <h1 class="contact-content">Contact Us</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="/contact"  id="contact">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name </label>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email"> Email </label>
              <br>
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message"> Messages </label>
              <br>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
          </form>
        </div>

        <video autoplay loop muted id="video">
          <source src="../images/contact-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="row questions-row" id="questions-row-id">
    <div class="container align-self-center questions-container" id="questions-container-id">
      <h4 class="questions-content">You may contact us if you have questions or clarifications about our services.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="row ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-content" id="footer-content">
        <h5 class="text-center footer-content">Copyright © 2020 02Pilot LLC</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- jQUERY -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AOS-->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- AOS-->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1500
    });
  </script>
  <!-- AJAX POST LINK-->
  <script src="javascripts/ajax.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help, can you explain a little why I had to change my ajax to not use the button click?

Comment: Click events are triggered earlier, the submit event fires after the click event. `submit` is used on a form, and indicates that the information is to be submitted to the server at this point unless you return false.
`click` is used on anything, and indicates that it was clicked, offering no other context to the intention of the event at all.
For example, you can have the `OnClick` event for the `#submit` button to bring up an alert that says "Is it correct?", and clicking "Ok" there can trigger the `OnSubmit` event, which would submit the form data to wherever you want it to go.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different way. In your situation i'll create a simple function to validate post and use a modal to show some errors or missing data. Use the return of the functiom that you create and use AJAX to POST the data on the server-side page instead of submit.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't insert the required attribute in the input tag. If you want a field to be required then you need to use it like the following

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I took all the required tags and form validation out because it was not working.